# Optional group not working in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following strings:

```
"What version is installed on production server?"
"What appserver version is installed on production server?"
"What system version is installed on production server?"
"What os version is installed on production server?"
```

And the following regex:

```
 /(?:what|which).*(appserver|system)?.*version.*\son\s(\w*).*/i
```

I would expect to get `appserver` or `system` or `undefined` as the first matching group but I always get `undefined`.

If I remove the `?` from the first matching group, I get `appserver` and `system` but the first and last string does not match anymore.

What is wrong?

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZVQTb/5/ for test bench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to look for anything up to "appserver" or "system", but when it's not there, there isn't another group before "version".

```
/(?:what|which).+?(appserver|system)?.*version.*\son\s(\w*).*/i
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVQTb/11/)

Note: changed `+` to `+?` per Evan's keen eyes.

Comment: It still gives 'undefined' :-(

Comment: I think you need to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVQTb/11/ Without the non-greedy +, I was still getting undefined on chrome.

Comment: Updated to reflect @Evan's comment.

Comment: Thanks it works but I don't understand why. Is the added ? applied on .+ or on the following matching group?

Comment: The `?` character in this context applies what precedes it - indicating the match should be non-greedy.

Comment: Changing the `*` to `+` wasn't the issue, it was the greediness of the first `.*`. So making it `.*?` would have been fine. Do you see why?